# Using Matplotlib and iPython, How to reset x and y axis limits to Autoscale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Using matplotlib and iPython, I have a bunch of plots that I am trying to view (one after the other).  Some plots only contain values from 0 to 1 and some contain values in the millions.

After setting the y axis limits using:

```
ylim((.7,1))
```

I want to be able to reset this to set the limits automatically (as it would have done before).  I am having trouble finding the correct approach.

Comment: Have you tried `ax.autoscale(True)`?

Comment: you probably need to call `draw()` to update the plot

Comment: This looks like it is working actually if I use clf() beforehand.  Thanks!

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it (when it will let you).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
ax = plt.gca()  # get the current axes
ax.relim()      # make sure all the data fits
ax.autoscale()  # auto-scale
# only needed mpl < 1.5
# ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()       # re-draw the figure
```

Comment: The `ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()` still seems necessary sometimes. thanks!